# Is there a way to encrypt a mounted file system for off-site backup?

Tags: linux, backup, encryption, ecryptfs, encfs

I want to efficiently back up an encrypted copy of my hard drive.  I am currently using rsync to backup an unencrypted copy, and I find it quite efficient.

I looked at duplicity and rsyncrypto, but duplicity makes incremental backups, and rsyncrypto uses a unique key for each encrypted file.  Duplicity also ran out of memory, and I would need to backup the rsyncrypto keys somewhere.  I find these to be space-inefficient, so I don't want to use them.

What I think would work well is if I could loopback/bind mount / and backup the encrypted mountpoint.  I looked at eCryptfs and EncFS, but they both seem to only mount encrypted directories, and not allow encrypting a mounted directory.  They both support encrypting the filename, which is also a desirable feature.

If I could have an encrypted version of my file system, then my existing rsync-backup would work efficiently.  When very little has changed, only the file names need to be encrypted.

Is there a way to encrypt a mounted directory as another directory?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ugh, i spent way too much time looking for an answer before posting this question, and now i find the `--reverse` option to `encfs` does what i want.  here's my backup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
CP="/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/rsync -aAhHPxX --delete-excluded --del --ignore-errors --rsync-path=\"rsync --fake-super\" $*"
SOURCE='/'
MOUNTPOINT='/tmp/slash'
DEST='backupuser@backuphost:backupdir'

mkdir -p $MOUNTPOINT
mount -t fuse.encfs | grep "^encfs on $MOUNTPOINT type fuse.encfs" || /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/encfs --reverse $SOURCE $MOUNTPOINT

#don't cross mount points
EXCLUDE_LIST=$(encfsctl encode $SOURCE `/usr/bin/cut -d\  -f 2 /proc/mounts | /bin/grep -v ^$SOURCE$`)
EXCLUDE=''
for EXCLUDE_ITEM in ${EXCLUDE_LIST} ; do
  EXCLUDE="${EXCLUDE} --exclude ${EXCLUDE_ITEM}"
done

/usr/bin/rsync -haxHAXPR $SOURCE/.encfs* $DEST/../
#eval for the quotes in the CP command
eval $CP $EXCLUDE $MOUNTPOINT/ $DEST/
```

and to recover a file:

```
CP='/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/rsync -haxHAXPR --no-implied-dirs --rsync-path="rsync --fake-super"';
SOURCE='/';
DEST='backupuser@backuphost:backupdir';
MOUNTPOINT='/tmp/slash';
ENCRYPTED_NAME=$(encfsctl encode $SOURCE $*);
eval $CP $DEST/./$ENCRYPTED_NAME $MOUNTPOINT
```